# How to style a jQuery button that is replaced with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button which I am styling with jQuery.  When the document is ready I run the following code:

```
$('button#refresh').button({
    icons: { primary: "ui-icon-refresh" },
    text: false
});
```

This has been working fine however now I am replacing the contents of the div that contains the button with some content retrieved via ajax.  The new content also contains a button with `id="refresh"` and I would like this to be styled with jQuery to.  How do I go about this?

I think my button refresh code needs to be bound to an event on the div, but what event?

Thanks!

Comment: `id` is unique, you need to use `class` or different name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call the button styiling script inside ajax success callback function again.

```
 $.ajax({
  ...
  success:function(data){
    //your stuff
    $('button#refresh').button({
      icons: { primary: "ui-icon-refresh" },
      text: false
    });
  }
```

NOTE": `The new content also contains a button with id="refresh"` looks like you have two IDs with a same name .... **ID  should always be unique**.. so make it class and use class selector..

```
 $('button.refresh').button({
   ......
```

Comment: Also... the ID must be unique within a given HTML document.  `The new content also contains a button with id="refresh"`

Comment: Thanks bipen, this makes sense.  I'll give it a try tomorrow.  The new content that I am pulling in contains button#refresh, but since this replaces the existing button#refresh content, it should be fine, shouldn't it?

Comment: yes it should.. :).. if it si replacing then i guess you don't need to use class to.. anyways welcome.. let me know if problem exists